# Is it possible to use Amazon Echo as a normal bluetooth microphone for a PC?

Tags: amazon-echo, microphones

Amazon Echo contains multiple good microphones. Is it possible to link them to my PC so that I can use the microphone with software like Skype?

Comment: Did you ever get echo working with Skype?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope.

There are currently just two Bluetooth profiles supported.

> **Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)**
>   This profile allows you to stream audio from your mobile device (such as a phone or tablet) to Echo.
>
> **Audio / Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP)**
>   This profile allows you to use hands-free voice control when a mobile device is connected to your Echo.

([Amazon Support Page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201727450))

Comment: I don't quite understand why the answer is no? Doesn't AVRCP imply using the device as a microphone. So doesn't this mean that you can use the Echo as a microphone as well as a speaker on, say, Windows 10 without the need of Alexa interfering?

Comment: @BramVanroy Apparently, no. "AVRCP: Audio/Video Remote Control Profile* is a Bluetooth profile that allows Bluetooth devices to control media playback on remote devices. It is typically used with A2DP devices for next/previous track selection and pause/play functions."